# Pesudocode to Java

Tags: java

What does the  'if (id E (n; [successor] )' means in Java?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(peer-to-peer)

everywhere is puting this, but I have no idea how this can be implemented in Java
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `E` here is the mathematical notation for "element of".

`id E (n, successor]` reads: `id` is element of the interval `(n, successor]`.  The interval is the half-closed interval of numbers from `n` to `successor`, where `successor` is in the interval, but `n` is not (hence half-closed)

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, I'd say `n < id <= successor`

Java:  `if (n < id && id <= successor)`

Comment: how do u translate this too    for i = m downto 1

Answer (score 1):

How about this:
[jCord: A simple Java implementation of Chord protocol](https://code.google.com/p/joonion-jchord)

Thanks Google (2nd link)

Comment: i download the source, i still have no idea what he is doing heh